# Display image in full screen from gridview onClick

Tags: android, android-intent, gridview, imageview

I'm trying to displaying local images from a specific directory in Gridview and now i want to display the full image when i click on the gridview thumbnail in new activity.I'm new to android and I have searched the internet for past two days and can't find anything that will help me. Hope anyone here will help.
Here is my code.

PictureRecyclerAdapter.java

```
private ArrayList<File> filesList;
    private Activity activity;
    Context context;
 public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView thumbnail;
        ImageButton imageDownload, imageShare;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            thumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pictures_thumbnail);
            imageDownload = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageDownload);
            imageShare = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageShare);
        }
    }

    public pictureRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<File> filesList, Activity activity) {
        this.filesList = filesList;
        this.activity = activity;
    }


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View inflatedView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.pictures_item_view, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(inflatedView);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final File currentFile = filesList.get(position);
        Glide.with(activity).load(currentFile.getAbsolutePath())
                .skipMemoryCache( false )
                .crossFade().into(holder.thumbnail);
        holder.imageDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    copyFile(currentFile, new File( DIRECTORY_TO_SAVE_MEDIA_NOW+currentFile.getName()),activity);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        holder.thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent go = new Intent(activity, ImageDetailsActivity.class);
                go.putExtra("image",  FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",currentFile));
                activity.startActivity(go);
            }
        });
```

And here is my PictureActivity

```
public class pictures extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private static final String IMAGE_LOCATION = "/storage/emulated/0/Image Folder/";

    public pictures() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pictures, container, false);

        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.pictures_recyclerView);
        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new ItemDecorationAlbumColumns(
                getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.photos_list_spacing),2));
        getListFiles(new File(IMAGE_LOCATION));
        pictureRecyclerAdapter ra = new pictureRecyclerAdapter(this.getListFiles(new File(IMAGE_LOCATION)), getActivity());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(ra);

        return v;
    }

    private ArrayList<File> getListFiles(File parentDir) {
        ArrayList<File> inFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
        File[] files;
        files = parentDir.listFiles();
        if (files != null) {
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.getName().endsWith(".jpg") ||
                        file.getName().endsWith(".png") ||
                        file.getName().endsWith(".jpeg")) {
                    if (!inFiles.contains(file))
                        inFiles.add(file);
                }
            }
        }
        return inFiles;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display image in ImageDetailsActivity,pass image file path in intent and start activity.

```
holder.thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent go = new Intent(activity, ImageDetailsActivity.class);
            go.putExtra("image",currentFile.getAbsolutePath());
            activity.startActivity(go);
        }
    });
```

Then in detail activity onCreate method, get path and display it using either glide or something else.

```
if(getIntent() != null){
  String path = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
  Glide.with(this)
    .load(path)
    .into(imageView);
}
```

Comment: Works smoothly, Can i use the same method for videos

Comment: You can pass video file path to another activity with this way. But you need another approach to play video since glide is not capable of playing video.If you just wanna show video thumbnail with glide,I refer to this link (https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-displaying-gifs-and-videos)

Comment: if(getIntent() != null){
            String path = getIntent().getStringExtra("video");

            videoView.setVideoPath(path);
            MediaController mc = new MediaController(this,false);
            videoView.setMediaController(mc);
            videoView.setFitsSystemWindows(true);
            mc.show(0);
            mc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
            videoView.start();   did this it works just fine